# function gives warning when run through dplyr::summarise, not otherwise

Tags: r, dplyr, fitdistrplus

I'm using `fitdistrplur::fitdist` to fit distributions. The results look fine but I am getting lots of warnings about `dnorm()` (or whichever distribution I use) returning NaN, but only when I run the analysis through `dplyr:summarise()`. If I call `fitdist()` without using `summarise()` there is no warning.

Here is a reprex. This is with R 4.3.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(fitdistrplus)
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'MASS'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     select
#> Loading required package: survival
fun <- function(data, distr = "norm"){
  fitdist(
        data = data,
        distr = distr,
        keepdata = FALSE, method = "mme"
      )

return(1)
}


tibble(x = rnorm(100)) |> 
  summarise(fun(x))
#> Warning: There were 2 warnings in `summarise()`.
#> The first warning was:
#> ℹ In argument: `fun(x)`.
#> Caused by warning in `dnorm()`:
#> ! NaNs produced
#> ℹ Run `dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings()` to see the 1 remaining warning.
#> # A tibble: 1 × 1
#>   `fun(x)`
#>      <dbl>
#> 1        1

fun(tibble(x = 1:100)$x)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I've tried the full range of debugging techniques I know - setting the debugger on `dnorm` etc, and cannot find what is causing the problem.

Currently I am using the workaround of wrapping `fitdist()` in `suppressWarnings()` but I don't think this is a great solution.

Comment: Your "reprex" does not produce an error on my end. However, if you remove ` return(1)` you will find that it throws another error entirely explaining you're passing a fitdist object instead of a vector.

Comment: My full code processes the fitdist object to make a data.frame. What version of R are you using?

Comment: As we don't have a MWE that reproduces the error, no way of knowing. Ran it on 2 machines with recent and old R/dplyr. To make this a MWE as well: 1. Pass the same data to both functions with a set seed. In the first you're using rnorm(100) and in the second you're using 1:100. 2. Get rid of return(1) as it's returning 1 and presumably irrelevant.  Without reproducing the error, you most likely are doing something to create a negative standard deviation as dnorm() only throws an error in such cases. But you're also using norm with mme and rnorm() so this shouldn't be an issue.